# Performance tuning: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.Basicresourcepool.Awaitavailable() method takes most of application's running time

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, profiling, c3p0

I have application which inserts in database chunks of data in parallel (Technically a lot of native INSERT queries gets executed on EntityManager object).

I'm now trying to understand how to speed up these inserts. There are no any significant processor load and io wait time on database hosts as well as on application's host and almost no latency between the servers.
In VisualJVM sampler I can see that about 80% of application's running time is spent by  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.Basicresourcepool.Awaitavailable() method.

Does anybody know what exactly this method is doing? I tried increase/decrease connection pool max_size number in JPA's connection pooling related properties, however didn't see any significant difference.
Any other advises how to speed up inserts are appreciated.

See properties of EntityManagerFactory bean providing persistence to the application below:

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
hibernate.connection.username=
hibernate.connection.password=
hibernate.connection.driver_class=jpa.connection.driver_class
hibernate.connection.url=
hibernate.connection.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
hibernate.connection.autoReconnect=true
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=3
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=100 /* tried different values - not much difference  */
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=1800 
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=15000 
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.validate=false
hibernate.c3p0.format_sql=false
hibernate.c3p0.show_sql=false
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=240
hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime=0
```

Comment: one quick suggestion: acquireIncrement should never be one. that guarantees lots of time in awaitAvailable as the pool scales up. if maxPoolSize is 100, something like 10 would be a more appropriate acquireIncrement.

Comment: Please add a table definition to your question (`create table xxx(...)`) with all indexes and triggers if any exists.

Comment: Whenever you have function `blah` taking 80% of time, and you don't know why, grab a stack sample. It will show you why, with 80% probability.

Answer (score 1):

Try to batch your INSERT queries. I.e. collect some amount of data for several INSERTs and run it as a single INSERT query.